# How to delete icon from Homescreen programmatically on Android

Tags: android

i am use this code for delete icon from homescreen:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
                p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But after click button "Delete Icon", app closes, I need to remove the icon and use the application on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable the app and still continue using it.
Your code above puts the app into disabled state. The PackageManager will not allow the app to run unless it is re-enabled.

If you want your app to still run, but not have an icon in the all apps drawer of your homescreen, you can by removing the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` from your activity reference in your AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".HiddenActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The app will not appear in the all apps drawer of your home screen, but can be launched from other apps using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("app_package_name", "app_package_name.HiddenActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Note: The app with the HiddenActivity must have been started by the user after installing, otherwise the app will be in Stopped state and can't be launched from another application.

Comment: Thank you, but i am need read tutorial, how to delete icon from Homescreen and dont crash app.